# nginx location doesn't work without root, despite root being in server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have an nginx config with the root specified in the server block. According to pages like this (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/), that should be enough, without also needing to put the same root in the location / block. But unless I do put a root directive in the location / block, I get a 404 error. Here's my server block:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mysite.com

    root /usr/local/nginx/sites/mysite;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root /usr/local/nginx/sites/mysite;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

So if "`root /usr/local/nginx/sites/mysite;`" is inside `location /`, everything works. But if it's not, it's like the same root directive in the server block is just ignored. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing a `;` on the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mysite.com; # <--- Missing semicolon

    root /usr/local/nginx/sites/mysite;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root /usr/local/nginx/sites/mysite;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

This would cause nginx to be blind to the `root` attribute, as such keywords must appear first as separated by curly braces or a semicolon.